# Oracle instant client can't execute sql update

Tags: python, oracle, pyodbc, cx-oracle, instantclient

I can connect to a Oracle 10g release 2 server using instant client. Using pyodbc and cx_Oracle.

Using either module, I can execute a select query without any problems, but when I try to update a table, my program crashes.

For example,

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 = 'value';` works fine.

`UPDATE table SET col2 = 'value' WHERE col1 = 'val';` does not work

Is this a known limitation with instant client, or is there a problem with my installation?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: is there an error message or code?  i guess permissions are read only.

Comment: I agree with john: "does not work" is not a valid Oracle error message

Answer (score 1):

Use the instant client with SQL*Plus and see if you can run the update. If there's a problem, SQL*Plus is production quality, so won't crash and it should give you a reasonable error message.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds more like your user you are connecting with doesn't have those privileges on that table.  Do you get an ORA error indicating insufficient permissions when performing the update?